# can I make this animation slow in css?

Tags: html, css-animations

What is going on this code ? how it is functioning and how can i change its animation ?

```css
h2 {
  font-family: cursive;
}

h1 {
  color: brown;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: typing 4.5s steps(450, end), blink-caret .95s step-end infinite;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hi</h1>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/

Comment: Code is incomplete. Kindly add the code for `animation typing`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the animation properties by editing the animation shorthand, the canonical order of the animation shorthand is as follows:
`animation: keyframesName animation-duration animation-iteration-count`
You can slow the animation by increasing the animation-duration in the CSS like this:

```css
h1 {
  color: brown;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: typing 8s steps(450, end), blink-caret .95s step-end infinite;
}
```

so in the above CSS, the timing is changed in the animation shorthand.

Also, your animation is not working because you haven't specified the keyframes, just specify the keyframes which are available at the link you specified in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
h1 {
  font-family: cursive;
}

h1 {
  
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 9s;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: blue;}
}
</style>
  </head>
<body>

<h1>Hi</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

hello - your code is incompelete .
Your code should look like the above and the tags should be applied to it.
When you specify CSS styles inside the @keyframes rule, the animation will gradually change from the current style to the new style at certain times.
The following example binds the "example" animation to the  element. The animation will last for 9 seconds, and it will gradually change the background-color of the  element from "red" to "blue"

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can slow it up by adding some feature like increase animation Seconds

```
animation:10s
```

also You can Use this Code here

```
    h1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One alternative you can use to your current method is to change the width and position of the h1 so that your animation can extend fully across the text only.

Right now, your header extends the full width of the browser, so through experimenting, we can deduce that it is `50px`, and then use `float: left`

Next, we need to edit the animation. Normally, we would want 1 letter to appear at a time, so since the word "hi" is two letters, we can do this in 2 steps, and in 1 second (the time for the animation is totally up to you).

Putting this altogether, along with editing the animation:

```
h2 {
    font-family: cursive;
  }
  
  h1 {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    color: brown;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
    /* The typwriter cursor */
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* Keeps the content on a single line */
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
    letter-spacing: .15em;
    /* Adjust as needed */
    animation: typing 1s steps(2), blink .5s infinite alternate;
  }
    
    /* text animation */
    
    @keyframes typing{
      0%{
        width: 0
      }
    }
    
    /* cursor animations */
    
     @keyframes blink{
        50% {
          border-color: transparent
        }
      }
```

If you want the animation to be slower, you can increase the time it takes for the animation to complete by editing this line (you would increase the 1s after typing to something like 2s):

```
    animation: typing 1s steps(2), blink .5s infinite alternate;
```